# YouCompleteMe on remote files

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me

I use YouCompleteMe on vim and it works great for me on the files in my local machine. However, when I open files in a remote server, for example, using

```
:e scp://user@remote//path/to/file.cpp
```

None of my YouCompleteMe based completion works.

I see that the above `scp` command, copies the remote file to local disk, and copies it back to the remote location whenever I do `:w`. And it is very weird to me that `YouCompleteMe` has no completion suggestions!

What can I do for the YouCompleteMe suggestions to start working again?

Comment: I'd wager this is entirely dependent on how YouCompleteMe configures itself and knows what completion to provide. (Aside: for the time being, the `<C-X>` family really isn't bad—I love it)

Comment: netrw (vim's built-in plugin that handles remote files) is [blacklisted by default in YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/blob/master/doc/youcompleteme.txt#L2565). maybe try `let g:ycm_filetype_blacklist.netrw=0`?